# maven classpathentry includes is ignoring pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, classpath, pom.xml

I am trying to include next to `**/*.java` also `**/*.properties` to my `.classpath` in my Maven project but it is not working at all.

I tried the tutorial on https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/specifying-source-path-inclusions-and-exclusions.html

but it does not affect anything in my `.classpath` file at all.

here is the relevant part of my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"...>
    <build>

    <scriptSourceDirectory>F:\07 Krauck-Systems\Workspace\git\PCMS\KSFramework\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>F:\07 Krauck-Systems\Workspace\git\PCMS\KSFramework\src\com\ks\framework\test</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>F:\07 Krauck-Systems\Workspace\git\PCMS\KSFramework\bin</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>F:\07 Krauck-Systems\Workspace\git\PCMS\KSFramework\bin\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>


    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <sourceInclude>**/*.properties</sourceInclude>
                </sourceIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
[...]
</project>
```

here is the resulting classpathentry:

```xml
<classpath>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="bin" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    [...]
</classpath>
```

**UPDATE:**

after using the pom recommended in the first answer, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/test/resources"/>


    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/User Libraries"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/collectionUtils/commons-collections4-4.0.jar" sourcepath="libs/collectionUtils/commons-collections4-4.0-sources.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/commons-net-3.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/mailapi.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/smtp.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/joda-time-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/commons-collections4-4.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/velocity-1.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/log4j-api-2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/log4j-core-2.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/junit/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/antlr-2.7.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/avalon-logkit-2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/jdom-1.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/log4j-1.2.12.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/maven-ant-tasks-2.0.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/oro-2.0.8.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/servletapi-2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/velocity/werken-xpath-0.9.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

the problem is, that I still have to add:

```
|**/*.properties
```

in

```
<classpathentry including="**/*.java|**/*.properties" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
```

to make it work (recognize the config.properties file). any so unfortunately it hasn't solved my problem. is there anything else wrong?

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Did you update the M2Eclipse plugin to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the `maven-eclipse-plugin` for your use-case. Maven is integrated in Eclipse thanks to [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). This is actually advertised on the [homepage](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) of the `maven-eclipse-plugin`:

> Users are advised to use m2e, the Eclipse Maven Integration instead of this plugin, as it can more closely resemble the actual build and runtime classpaths as described in the project pom.xml - among other advantages.

Reading your `pom.xml`, I notice that you are not following the Maven conventions and it is the source of your problem.

I suggest you follow these steps to get you started correctly:

- Install (or update) M2Eclipse. This is done by going to "Help > Install New Software..." and selecting the following URL: `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/`.
- Place all your main Java source files inside the folder `src/main/java`.
- Place all your test Java source files inside the folder `src/test/java`.
- Place all your main resources (i.e. your properties file) inside `src/main/resources`.
- Place all your test resources (i.e. your properties file) inside `src/test/resources`.
- Replace your POM with this simple one.

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"...>
      <build>
          <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.1</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <source>1.7</source>
                      <target>1.7</target>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  </project>
  ```
- Update your Maven project in Eclipse by right-clicking the project and going to "Maven > Update Project...".

As a rule of thumb, you should try to always follow those conventions: they are used by every Maven developer and make it easy to understand your build process.

Comment: Hi, I have created this structure as you recommended, and put the config.properties into src/main/resources. But after a update it creates this: <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/> and this does not include the *.properties. any further ideas?

Comment: @Niko Try to reduce your POM to as little as possible (like my example), update M2Eclipse, select "Project > Clean" from Eclipse and update the Maven project "Maven > Update Project...". On my machine, the POM in my answer produces the following classpath entry: <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>